# zsh: command not found: psql in mac terminal

Tags: python, postgresql, zsh, psql

I've got this error when I type 'psql' in my terminal : "`zsh: command not found: psql`".

i only got this when I open `~/.zshrc` :

- `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions`

I've installed postgresql version 11-15 on my Mac.

Now what do I do to run psql without any error?

Comment: IIRC command line are located at `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

Comment: Is there an **executable** file `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/psql`?

Comment: Yuri's comment is suggesting you run `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin` and see if that works. If it does, edit your `$HOME/.zshrc` to match.

Comment: Yes, it works when i add '/latest/bin'. My bad. Thank you so much @YuriGinsburg and Mark!!

Answer (score 1):

you'd need to add in the path for the bin folder onto your .zshrc to makesure that it reads it. I see that you have exported -

`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions`

While this is partly correct, you need to include the `bin/` folder in it for it to read the `psql` script.

`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

would do the trick, make sure to add it in your `.zshrc` file and restart your terminal to get it working.

Comment: Yes, it works when i add '/latest/bin'. Thank you, Abdul!!

Comment: @Asyraf pleasure :)